# Unable to upgrade Android SDK from 22.6.3 to 23.0.6

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am having the Android SDK version 22.6.3 and ADT version 23.0.6

I tried to upgrade SDK version to 23.0.6 using SDK manager. But there are no new installation packages available.

Please help me on upgrading my Android SDK version from 23.0.6 to 22.6.3

Answer (score 0):

Please check the android update channel if you want beta channels change the stable into beta and get the new versions
1) Go to Settings
2) select Appearance & Behavior
3) System Settings
4) Choose Updates
5) Change the channels

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without losing data or need not delete eclipse:

Download latest version of [ADT][1] u can see the adt version starts with ADT-23.0

At Eclipse - Help - Install new software - Uncheck Contact all update sites during install to find required software (bottom, last preference) in order to avoid any unwanted delays during install.

Click on Add - Archive - select the zip file u downloaded